# How to set Android Action Bar Tab scroll style

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have read a load of posts on styling the Android Action Bar and have successfully created my own style of Tab Menu items.

In the specific situation where there are many Tabs and the honeycomb device goes into Portrait mode, the Action Bar automatically makes the Tabs horizontally scrollable. What I couldn't figure out is a way to hide the blue holo scrollbars when the tabs are scrolling left and right and reaches the end.

I'm trying to remove the blue bars shown here:
[image]

Can anyone help?

My current style looks like this:

```
   <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item> 
        <item name="android:scrollbars">none</item>                
    </style>

    <!-- style for the tabs -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/moto_tab_indicator</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_background</item>               
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity android:name=".ActivityName" android:theme="@style/tabTheme"/>
```

> In values/styles.xml:

```
 <style name="tabTheme" parent="android:style/Theme"> 
      <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/Widget.TabWidget</item>
 </style> 

 <style name="Widget.TabWidget" parent="android:Theme"> 
      <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the blue scrollbars for me, have you seen this solution work?